# How to control Ngb bootstrap carousel slide by button in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I have a scenario like this:

- Display Ngb Bootstrap carousel and control the slide images by two buttons: Previous and Next.
- When Previous button was clicked then show previous slide image and Next button was clicked then show next slide image.
- Unfortunately, my code doesn't work. Someone can help me. Below are my code:

1. HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper-md">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">TITLE HERE</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ngb-carousel #carousel *ngIf="images" [showNavigationArrows]="false" [showNavigationIndicators]="false"  [keyboard]="false">
            <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of images; index as i">
                <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                    <img [src]="image" alt="Guide image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Slide {{i}}</h4>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-carousel>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-r" *ngIf="!isNext" (click)="skip()">Skip</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info m-r" *ngIf="isNext" (click)="previousStep()">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="nextStep()">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. TypeScript code:

```
    images = [62, 83, 466, 965, 982, 1043, 738].map((n) => `https://picsum.photos/id/${n}/900/500`);

    @ViewChild('carousel', {static: true}) carousel: NgbCarousel;

    isPrevious: boolean = false;
    isNext: boolean = false;

    constructor(public modal: NgbActiveModal){

    }

    skip()
    {
        this.modal.close();
    }

    previousStep()
    {
        this.isPrevious = true;
        this.carousel.prev();
    }

    nextStep()
    {
        this.isNext = true;
        this.carousel.next();

    }
```

Any idea in my case.
Thank in advance!

Comment: Welcome, SangBui! If u could provide stackblitz with reproduction, it would be more chance to find an answer.
You might need trigger change detection manually. It is difficult to give better advice.

Comment: Hi IAfanasov, because I can't install bootstrap carousel in Stackblizt so that I can't reproduce it. But I changed my solution to an popup video. Thank for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Remove [showNavigationArrows]="false" this attribute
explain---if youuse ngb-carousal this attribue is false then your next and pre event is not work by default it is true
and inside ngb-carouse you can use next and pre button

```
    <div class="wrapper-md">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">TITLE HERE</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ngb-carousel #carousel *ngIf="images" [showNavigationIndicators]="false"  [keyboard]="false">
            <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of images; index as i">
                <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                    <img [src]="image" alt="Guide image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Slide {{i}}</h4>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-r" *ngIf="!isNext" (click)="skip()">Skip</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info m-r" *ngIf="isNext" (click)="previousStep()">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="nextStep()">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
        </ngb-carousel>`
    </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).